# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Tags: administration, central-administration, farm-admin

I am trying to access my web-application , But finding no luck to navigate with error **"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. "**

My all services in services.msc(sql,sharepoint,IIS) and IIS status are running fine .Could any one help me what's the reason and how can I solve it

Answer (score 1):

Can u give us more log, like log of sharepoint and eventsviewrs.

Can u add this key in your Web.Config to see if it resolve the probleme :

In "web.config" under "appSettings":

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000" />
```